# Passing an WinRT object type through non-WinRT code.

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a application set up like a three layer cake: where the upper and lower layers support WinRT but the middle does not. Those upper and lower WinRT layers need to share a reference to the application's CoreWindow object but their only communication channel is through the middle layer. I can only pass it through the middle non-WinRT layer. How do I pass the CoreWindow object through the middle non-WinRT layer?

Casting from CoreWindow^ to void* doesn't give me any complaints from the compiler, but casting back to CoreWindow^ gives me type conversion errors.

Comment: Hehe, a bit of C++/CLI legacy left behind in the compiler there.

Comment: Deep inside, it's a COM interface pointer. Feel free to pass as `IUnknown*`. `reinterpret_cast`, in the context of C++/CX, compiles to a QueryInterface() call.

Comment: What Seva said - if you have a winrt object and need to deal with it from a non C++/CX element, use IUnknown - all winrt interfaces derive directly from IInspectable and IInspectable derives directly from IUnknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figure it out only after posting: I used reinterpret_cast< CoreWindow^ >(windowPtr).